# How to configure the Keycloak Truststore via Terraform?

Tags: terraform, keycloak, terraform-provider-aws, mtls

I'm trying to configure my Keycloak server via Terraform. I want to use mTLS for client authentication in Keycloak, that's why I'm trying to find out, how to configure my Keycloak truststore via Terraform.

In the Website of Terraform I could already find [here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/mrparkers/keycloak/latest/docs/resources/realm_keystore_java_keystore), how to configure the keystore of Keycloak. Accourding to the truststore I couldn't find anything. Does anyone know, how to reach this case with Terraform?

Thanks in advance.